# iOS - in house distribution without ssl

Tags: ios, in-house-distribution

Recently we got ios enterprise certificate for in-house distribution.
We succeeded in creating provisionings but now we are not quite sure with the way we distribute the app to our employees.

What is the most typical way to distribute in-house app?
Is it okay to use 3rd party cloud such as Azure/AWS? We do not have ssl certificate for our domain.

We are all new to this field so any advice will be appreciated greatly.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Distribution of Apple Enterprise Apps for iOS requires a so-called manifest. This acts as an instruction for the respective terminal for the installation of apps independent of the App Store.

please follow these instructions:

1. Prepare web server

Prepare access to a web server accessible via HTTPS. Access via FTP or SCP is required.

2. Deposit App Binary on server

Download the Binary File (.ipa) app for iOS sent by PressMatrix via FTP / SCP to your web server.

3. Create a manifest for installation

Create a manifest.plist file with the following structure and replace the following values ​​with the information appropriate to your app:

URL
Full web address URL to your app binary (.ipa) on your web server (https: //).
Bundle Identifier
The bundle ID for your app can be found in the PressMatrix app production e-mail
Bundle version
The bundle version for your app can be found in the PressMatrix App Production E-mail
title
Name of your app
Example manifest.plist:

```
<? xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<! DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "- // Apple // DTD PLIST 1.0 // EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version = "1.0">
  <Dict>
    <Key> items </ key>
    <Array>
      <Dict>
        <Key> assets </ key>
        <Array>
          <Dict>
            <Key> child </ key>
            <String> software package </ string>
            <Key> url </ key>
            <String> https://www.meinserver.de/MeineApp.ipa </ string>
          </ Dict>
        </ Array>
        <Key> metadata </ ​​key>
        <Dict>
          <Key> bundle-identifier </ key>
          <String> com.pressmatrix.meineapp </ string>
          <Key> bundle-version </ key>
          <String> 1.0 </ string>
          <Key> child </ key>
          <String> software </ string>
          <Key> title </ key>
          <string> My app name </ string>
        </ Dict>
      </ Dict>
    </ Array>
</ Dict>
</ Plist>
```

4th Mainfest on server deposit

Download the created manifest for iOS via FTP / SCP to your web server.

5. Create installation link

Create an ITMS services link (iTunes Music Store) with the full web address of your manifest file as a parameter (URL)
Example:

itms-services: // action = download-manifest & url = https: //mein.webserver.de/manifest.plist

Comment: Hi thanks for this instruction but as I wrote, we do not have https so we cannot host a web server via https. In this case, is it okay to host app in 3rd party cloud and distribute it from there to our employees? Or is it restricted by Apple?

Comment: It is okay to host app in 3rd party cloud!

Comment: Oh yes! I will try now.